# kubernetes how to call full service name instead of AWS node ip

Tags: kubernetes

I'm running my application EKS cluster, few days back we encounter the issues, let say we have application pod is running with one replicas count in different AWS node lets call vm name as like below.

```
ams-99547bd55-9fp6r               1/1     Running   0          7m31s   10.255.114.81    ip-10-255-12-11.eu-central-1.compute.internal   
mongodb-58746b7584-z82nd          1/1     Running   0          21h   10.255.113.10   ip-10-255-12-11.eu-central-1.compute.internal
```

Here the my running serivces

```
NAME                TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
ams-service         NodePort    172.20.81.165    <none>        3030:30010/TCP               18m
mongodb-service     NodePort    172.20.158.81    <none>        27017:30003/TCP              15d
```

I have setting.conf.yaml file running as config map where i have application related configuration

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: ama-settings
  labels:
    conf: ams-settings
data:
  config : |
 "git": {
      "prefixUrl": "ssh://git@10.255.12.11:30001/app-server/repos/ams/",
      "author": {
      "name": "app poc",
      "mail": "app@domain.com"
    },

      "mongodb": {
      "host": "10.255.12.11",
      "port": "30003",
      "database": "ams",
      "ssl": false,
     }
```

This is working as we expected, but in case if existing node ip where my pod is running, some of the reason when i'm deleting my running pod and trying to re-deploy that time my pod is placed in some other AWS node basically EC2 vm.

During this time my application is not working then I need edit my setting.conf.yaml file to update with new AWS node IP where my pod is running.

Here the question how to use the service name instead of AWS node IP, because we don't want change the ip address frequently in case if any existing VM is goes down.

Comment: You should in fact be able to use the service name `mongodb-service` instead of the node's IP address; I'm a little surprised the node IP works at all here.  (You shouldn't usually care about the node IP addresses at all.)  What happens if you make this change?

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the response, when I use service name mongodb-service, pod is running with error logs, mangodb connection no defined.

Comment: If I use aws node IP pod is up and running without any issue,  but what would be the case if existing vm destroyed and aws will launch another vm with some new IP, then I have edit my yaml file to update the IP address every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ideally, instead of using the AWS IP you should be using the `0.0.0.0/0` [Refrence doc](https://discuss.kubernetes.io/t/security-implications-of-binding-server-to-127-0-0-1-vs-0-0-0-0-vs-pod-ip/13880)

example in Node

```
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors());

const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
app.listen(port,"0.0.0.0" ,() => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

however, if you want to add the service name :

you can use the full certified name, but I am not sure it will work on as host `0.0.0.0` would be better option

```
<service.name>.<namespace name>.svc.cluster.local
```

example

```
ams-service.default.svc.cluster.local
```

Comment: Great ams-service.default.svc.cluster.local, but how we can spcify the port number  "mongodb": {
      "host": "10.255.12.11",
      "port": "30003",

Comment: use 3030 or whatever port of your service.

Comment: I have updated the service name  ams-service.default.svc.cluster.local but pod is not coming up

 Normal   Started    21s                kubelet            Started container cms
  Warning  Unhealthy  1s (x10 over 19s)  kubelet            Readiness probe failed: Get "https://10.255.112.102:3030/": dial tcp 10.255.112.102:3030: connect: connection refused

Comment: use 0.0.0.0 once instead service name

Comment: Nope, 0.0.0.0 also throwing same error

Comment: which application stack you are using, node with express or what ?

Comment: you are setting up proper port configuration to readiness also ? if you service running at 3030 and your readiness checking at 80 it wont work at all

Comment: share details what you have configured in configmap what is going to readiness confg etc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237441/discussion-between-gowmi-and-harsh-manvar).